# Is there a way to restart acpid on reboot?

Tags: debian, scripting, systemd, acpid

I've installed a package called `thinkpad-scripts`. Simply put its a bunch of scripts that activate various functionalities on thinkpad devices on linux that wouldn't work out of the box on fresh installations.

I've got the script to work and etc, but whenever I reboot my machine. The auto rotate functionality doesn't work when converting my laptop into tablet mode. I noticed the culprit has to do with `acpid`. When I restart `acpid` in terminal, it works again. Is there a way I can automate restarting `acpid` when I reboot, so I won't have to tediously do this over and over again ?

I'm running 64-bit Debian

EDIT: I tried making a cronjob with `crontab -e`

And wrote at the end of my file leaving a newline at the end

`@reboot sh $HOME/acpid_restart.sh`

The script `acpid_restart.sh` includes

```
#!/bin/sh 
systemctl restart acpid
```

But this still fails....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure `acpid.service` is actually being *started* during boot. After the host has rebooted, use this command to verify that:

```
# systemctl status acpid.service
```

It should say `started` and `enabled`. If it doesn't, then `systemctl enable acpid.service` might solve the problem for you, by actually starting the service on reboot.

Second, if the service is actually starting during boot, then check the logs to see if there is something wrong with it. You should already see some lines from the logs in the `systemctl status` output, then you can get more logs from that service using:

```
# journalctl -u acpid.service
```

You can also look at all the logs since the last reboot, with:

```
# journalctl -b
```

This might show other issues that can be related to the issue you're experiencing.

If it turns out `acpid.service` is actually starting during boot and screen rotation is not working before it's restarted, it's quite possible that it's being started too early in the boot process and that's what's causing it to misbehave until it gets restarted. Hopefully, if that's the case, the logs might provide you more details to allow you to fix that.

(Please post updates if you find something through this suggested troubleshooting, I'd be happy to give more pointers if you can be more specific about the symptoms you see.)

Finally, using cron to manage systemd services will most likely not really work as expected.

If you do want to force the service to restart sometime after booting, using a systemd timer unit is a better approach. You can either disable the service on boot and use a timer unit to actually start it once the system has been up for a while, or you can keep it enabled on boot and use a timer unit to trigger a separate service unit (`restart-acpid.service`, perhaps?) which uses `Type=oneshot` and executes the `/usr/bin/systemctl restart acpid.service` command (or the wrapper script which does essentially the same.)

However, that is pretty hacky. So I'd recommend you actually try to address the real problem by finding the root cause, rather than investing into such a clunky workaround for it.

Comment: Okay so apparently it wasn't started at all during boot. `systemctl enable acpid.service` resolved it all. It works on reboot, and no scripting or timer was needed. YOU ARE THE REAL MVP!!!

Comment: Glad this helped you @PrimRock, and good that it was a simple one to fix. Enjoy your auto rotating screen on tablet mode! 